# How to save estimated parameters from nigfit() in a variable

Tags: r, time-series, distribution, r-s4

I want to automatically fit time series returns into a NIG distribution.
With nigfit() from the package fBasics I estimate the mu, alpha, beta and delta of the distribution.

```
>   nigFit(histDailyReturns,doplot=FALSE,trace=FALSE)

Title:
 Normal Inverse Gaussian Parameter Estimation 

Call:
 .nigFit.mle(x = x, alpha = alpha, beta = beta, delta = delta, 
    mu = mu, scale = scale, doplot = doplot, span = span, trace = trace, 
    title = title, description = description)

Model:
 Normal Inverse Gaussian Distribution

Estimated Parameter(s):
       alpha         beta        delta           mu 
48.379735861 -1.648483055  0.012361539  0.001125734
```

This works fine, which means that nigfit plots my parameters.
However I would like to use the estimated parameters and save them in variables. So I could use them later.

```
    > variable = nigfit(histDailyReturns,doplot=FALSE,trace=FALSE)
```

This doesn't work out. 'variable' is an **S4 object** of class structure **fDISTFIT**. Calling the variable replots the output of nigfit above.
I tried the following notations, to get just one parameter:

```
    > variable$alpha
    > variable.alpha
    > variable[1]
```

I couldn't find an answer in the documentation of nigfit.
Is it possible to save the estimated parameters in variables? How does it work?

Comment: It worked out. I will write an answer, when stack overflow allows me to. (In eight hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access the output compenents using `@`. `variable` has different `slots`. Get their names using `slotNames()`. Using the example from the documentation:

```
    set.seed(1953)
    s <- rnig(n = 1000, alpha = 1.5, beta = 0.3, delta = 0.5, mu = -1.0)
    a <- nigFit(s, alpha = 1, beta = 0, delta = 1, mu = mean(s), doplot = TRUE) 
    slotNames(a)

     [1] "call"        "model"       "data"        "fit"         "title"      
     [6] "description"
    # `fit` is a list with all the goodies. You're looking for the vector, `estimate`:
    a@fit$estimate

         alpha       beta      delta         mu 
     1.6959724  0.3597794  0.5601027 -1.0446402
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the structure of the output object using `str(variable)`:

```
> variable@fit$par[["alpha"]]
[1] 48.379735861
> variable@fit$par[["beta"]]
[1] -1.648483055
> variable@fit$par[["delta"]]
[1] 0.012361539
> variable@fit$par[["mu"]]
[1] 0.001125734
```